# Importing Surface Colours along with .obj files in Fusion 360

Tags: 3d-models

I am currently involved in drone mapping and photogrammetry. I have taken some aerial images of a site from a drone, and have created a 3D map using DroneDeploy. I exported the 3D model from DroneDeploy as a .obj file and can view the model very well using Preview on my MacBook. However, when I import this .obj file to Fusion 360 or any other online viewing platform, I am unable to see any of the colours from the model.

How do I import this file into Fusion 360 along with all the surface colours? Do I need to convert the .obj file to some other format? If so, which formats support surface colours on Fusion?

Comment: Do you have a specific need for Fusion 360? If you just want to view an OBJ file there are better options around. Also, where does 3D printing come into it?